# Authentication using AccessToken / ServicePrincipal

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-ad-msal, sql-server-data-tools, entra

Am having a SSDT unit test project with EntraID authentication to my azure database.

This SSDT unit test project shall be executed (see image below):

- **Locally** in VS Code using the connection string +

  **Active Directory Interactive**Authentication
- And within my AzureDevOps Pipeline + Using ??Service Principal?? authentication

[image]

... this is the app.config for local execution:
[image]

How do i need to configure my app.config in order to use my ServicePrincipal from the AzureDevOps-Pipeline?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i need to configure my app.config in order to use my ServicePrincipal from the AzureDevOps-Pipeline?

To use the AAD Service Principal in the **app.config -> ConnectionString**, you can set the Authentication to **ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal**.

Here is an example:

```
Data Source=xx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={appid};Password={appsecret};Multiple Active Result Sets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal
```

If you want to avoid storing sensitive information in a connection string in app.config. You can store the connectionString in a [secret variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#secret-variables) in your pipeline.

And use tokens `connectionString="#{sqlDbTestConnectionString}#"` in app.config in place of real connection strings.

Then add [replace token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) before VsTest task in your pipeline to replace the tokens `#{sqlDbTestConnectionString}#` in app.config with the real connectionString defined in secret variable.

You can check [this blog](https://shanmugamchinnappa.medium.com/securely-configuring-azure-devops-pipeline-for-sql-unit-testing-be81f4c2cc10) for more information.