# Can I use a ServicePrincipal for authentication at Azure SQL with Microsoft Entra

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, microsoft-entra-id

I am following the How-To for authentication at SQL databases at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16

My issue is: I don't have a managed identity; I only have a service principal.

How do I need to write the connection string in order to use that service principal instead of a managed identity?

[image]

Comment: [15 minutes ago you were advised...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77925683/authentication-using-accesstoken-serviceprincipal#comment137379316_77925683)

Comment: In that web page you've linked to, there's an **explicit** paragraph titled "Using service principal authentication" - have you looked at that ??

Comment: Oh thanks @marc_s, i missed that i can read the servicePrincipalId + servicePrincipalKey out of my environment variables in the devOps agent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Service Principals as a way to authenticate applications and services.

If you're connecting to Azure Storage using a service principal, the connection string would typically include the following elements:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;
AccountName=yourstorageaccount;
AccountKey=youraccountkey;
SharedAccessSignature=yoursharedaccesssignature;
EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;
```

NOTE: The above is a sample.

Based on the above example, you will need to replace *AccountKey* by using the service principal's application ID and the *SharedAccessSignature* with its secret (or client secret).

The structure should look like:

```
Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal;
ApplicationId=yourApplicationId;
ApplicationKey=yourApplicationSecret;
TenantId=yourTenantId;
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;
AccountName=yourstorageaccount;
EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;
```

You will have to replace all the placeholders with their respective contents depend on what you're connecting to.